# Run systemd timer periodically but not on boot

Tags: boot, systemd, services, rtc

I would like to run a script every 30 minutes on my RbPi, **but not immediately after boot**. 
Example: If I boot my RbPi at 15:15, the script should run at 15:30 not before.
Setup: My RbPi has **no internet connection** to sync its time, it relies on an **external RTC**. To sync the time I followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306410).

What I did so far:
I have the following two files, generated using
`sudo systemctl edit --force --full test.service` and
`sudo systemctl edit --force --full test.timer`

```
# test.service
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=echo "TEST"

# test.timer
[Unit]
Description=test

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/30
Persistent=false

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Unfortunately this dummy script runs immediately during the boot sequence as shown by `journalctl -r`:

```
...

Oct 21 14:11:43 rbpi0 kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Oct 21 14:11:43 rbpi0 systemd[1]: Finished Online ext4 Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
Oct 21 14:11:43 rbpi0 systemd[1]: e2scrub_all.service: Succeeded.
Oct 21 14:11:43 rbpi0 systemd[1]: Starting Daily man-db regeneration...
Oct 21 14:11:43 rbpi0 systemd-udevd[128]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v247'.
Oct 21 14:11:43 rbpi0 bluetoothd[443]: Starting SDP server
Oct 21 14:11:43 rbpi0 systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Oct 21 14:11:43 rbpi0 bluetoothd[443]: Bluetooth daemon 5.55
Oct 21 14:11:43 rbpi0 echo[455]: TEST
Oct 21 14:11:43 rbpi0 systemd[1]: Starting test...
Oct 21 14:11:42 rbpi0 systemd[1]: Starting Online ext4 Metadata Check for All Filesystems...
Oct 21 14:11:42 rbpi0 kernel: rtc-rv3028 1-0052: setting system clock to 2023-10-21T14:11:42 UTC (1697897502)
```

How can I avoid my script to run during the boot sequence but run only at `*:30`?

Comment: Have a look at systemd timers. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.timer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Systemd scripts are run asynchronously as root before boot and is not suitable.

Linux has a tool `cron` to run tasks at a given time.

It can run after boot, yearly, monthly, weekly, daily, hourly etc. and can run as root or as a user.

See `man 5 crontab`

I use to turn the LED on my Pi on/off overnight and it is used by the OS to perform tasks e.g. monthly log rotation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how to use cron but this is not what I wanted to do. I will try to investigate if running my script as user will fix the issue.

Comment: In the end I changed to your solution: it is simply more reliable :) .

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably modify the script to check how long since boot.
Something like this (Bash syntax):

```
up_sec=$(sed 's/\..*//' /proc/uptime)
if ! (( up_sec > 15 * 60 )); then
    echo "Not up long enough yet ($up_sec), skipping"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Does this mean it is expected to run at boot?

Comment: It'd just run whenever it would run according to the OP.
The difference is when the script runs if it detects the host has been up on briefly then it would skip doing anything

Answer (score 0):

The Linux `at` command allows you to run something at a particular time. The time can be specified in different ways.

For the example in the question, run this command at boot-up:

`at -f /path/scriptname now + 15 minutes`

See the man page for further details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is not exactly what I wanted to do. I really need the script to be executed at 00 and 30, not just every 30 minutes. I'm looking for a solution that resolves the issue with systemd.

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!

The issue was that i dindn't initialized the time correctly.
Yes I followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306410) but I used a script that wrapped the `/sbin/hwclock --hctosys --utc --noadjfile` command, delaying it in time. This let the boot sequence to start already creating a mess with the `OnCalendar=` entry (as described in the [man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.timer.html) page).

I was enough to add a service exactly as [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306410), no need to change anything else.